# string to timestamp results always `01/01/1970 00:01:00`

Tags: php, date, datetime, datetimepicker

i am trying to convert a variable having date time as string to time stamp
with the code below it always gives the output as `01/01/1970 00:01:00` 
no matter what date time is present in the string

mydate is a datetimepicker

in mydate the date is set via

**functions.php**

```
$randnos=rand(0,30);
$randhrs=rand(00,24);
$randmin=rand(00,60);
$randsec=rand(00,60);

$ttxt='+'.$randnos.' days +'.$randhrs.' Hours +'.$randmin.' minutes +'.$randsec.' seconds';
$newTime = date("d/m/Y H:m:s",strtotime($ttxt));
update_post_meta($post_id,'mydate',$newTime);
```

**template**

```
$tdate=new DateTime();
$mystring=get_field('mydate');
$timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:m:s', $mystring)->getTimestamp();
$mystring= date("d/m/Y H:m:s", $timestamp );

if ($mystring>=$tdate){
echo "yahoo";
}
```

and it never passes the if condition plus it gives me the Call to a member function getTimestamp() on a non-object

Comment: dd/mm is not valid: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php Plus you're adding `.` to each end of the string.

Comment: I am curious if this works in functions.php `$newTime = date('d/m/Y H:m:s', time() + rand(0, 30*24*60*60) );` -- Adding a random number of seconds up to 30 days to current time... or `$timestamp =  time() + rand(0, 30*24*60*60); $newTime = date('d/m/Y H:m:s', $timestamp );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be strtotime can not read the time string and convert it to a timestamp.

How about using the [DateTime object](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) to convert the string

```
$mystring="25/12/2015 14:12:54";
$timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:m:s', $mystring)->getTimestamp();
echo $timestamp . '=' . date("d/m/Y H:m:s", $timestamp );
```

Comment: i get error Call to a member function getTimestamp() on a non-object

Comment: i assigned $mystring= date("d/m/Y H:m:s", $timestamp ); echo $mystring; sinc ei need to check the if condition...but i get the error

Comment: No, you need to check `$mystring=get_field('mydate');` since it does not give you a value!

Comment: it does echo the content correctly, but gives me timestamp error

Comment: plus when i do $mystring=DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:mm:ss', $mystring);var_dump($mystring); it gives bool(false);

Comment: Try 'd/m/Y **H:m:s**'. I tested the code in my answer, and it works!